# Attempt to invoke virtual method '...' on null object Reference

Tags: android, nullpointerexception

I have problem with my App ,, and want to solve it but i could not access to solution please help me ,,,

```
// Main_Activity Class

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    Button Open_play_list;
    AccessPlayList accessPL;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Open_play_list = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnShA);
        accessPL = new AccessPlayList();

        Open_play_list.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // Calling method tht contain code for open playlist
                try {
                    accessPL.openPlaylist();
                }`enter code here`
                catch (Exception ex) {
                    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), ex.getMessage().toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            }
        });
    }

// AccessPlayList Class

public class AccessPlayList extends Activity {

    Intent intentPL;
    int REQUEST_CODE = 1;
    int PLAYLIST_ID = 2;

    public void openPlaylist()
    {
        intentPL = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK);
        intentPL.setComponent(new ComponentName("com.android.music","com.android.music.PlaylistBrowserActivity"));
        intentPL.setType("MediaStore.Audio.Playlist.CONTENT_TYPE");
        intentPL.setFlags(0x10000000);
        intentPL.putExtra("oneShot",false);
        intentPL.putExtra("PlayList",PLAYLIST_ID);
        startActivityForResult(intentPL,REQUEST_CODE);
    }
}
```

Comment: Please post the exception stack trace and indicate which line it refers to.

Comment: Unlike forum sites, we don't use "Thanks", or "Any help appreciated", or signatures on [Stack Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com/). See ["Should 'Hi', 'thanks,' taglines, and salutations be removed from posts?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts)". BTW, it's "Thanks in advance", not "Thanks in advanced". Furthermore, you haven't actually told us *what* your problem is or explained what is going wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Since you did not post which line of your code is where the error is occurring, the only thing I can tell you is that you need to check if the object causing the problem is null.
Try some validation like this:

```
if(object != null){
    //do something
}
```